# How to create a multicontrol mcx gate or operation in cirq

Tags: quantum-gate, cirq

In qiskit the method to apply a multi control with more than 2 control qubits is:

```
qc.mct ( listcontrols,targetbit,listancillas, mode=mode[i])
```

What is the equivalent in Cirq for creating that operation to append to a cirquit?. 
What i need  is to decompose that operation into [RX,RY,RZ, X,H,CX], like in qiskit with transpile.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:
For creating an mct that will be executed:

```
q = cirq.LineQubit.range(6)
mymct = cirq.ControlledGate(sub_gate=cirq.X, num_controls=3)
opmymct=mymct(q[0],q[1],q[2],q[3])
```

And for decomposing it, if you are only intersted in the operation text, there are two steps. First call decompose_multi_controlled_x. The best number of free qubits(qfree) is numcontrols -2, and will output only two ccx, with much less instructions than qiskit and much faster:

```
d = cirq.decompose_multi_controlled_x(c,q[target],qfree)        
numinstrucs=len(d)
```

And then decompose each ccx (TOFFOLI) to [RX,RY,RZ, X,H,CX]  gates by using qiskit transpile, wich decomposes each ccx in 15 instructions.

```
def mymct2(qc,c,t):
    qc.h (t )
    qc.cx (c[1] , t )
    qc.rz(-np.pi/4 , t )
    qc.cx (c[0] , t )
    qc.rz(np.pi/4 , t )
    qc.cx (c[1] , t )
    qc.rz(np.pi/4 , c[1] )
    qc.rz(-np.pi/4 , t )
    qc.cx (c[0] , t )
    qc.cx (c[0] , c[1] )
    qc.rz(np.pi/4 , c[0] )
    qc.rz(-np.pi/4 , c[1] )
    qc.cx (c[0] , c[1] )
    qc.rz(np.pi/4 , t )
    qc.h (t )
```

I have try it with 100 control qubits and is fast. What I did is generate the text functions (mymctN)by using the above method. This is usefful because I will execute it in my simulator "bloch computer", witch does not uses state matrixs of 2**n qubits, so it can have lot of qubits, but needs that set of instructions.

Answer (score 0):

`cirq.X(target).controlled_by(a, b, ..., z)`